# How can I return Laravel controller to multiple view files?

Tags: laravel

I have these view files:

- `about.blade.php`
- `home.blade.php`
- `contact.blade.php`

I want to return all of them using one controller function `index()`:

```
public function index()
{
    return view(['about', 'contact', 'home']);
}
```

Comment: use Laravel View Composer , using view composer you can share data  in all these pages

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you want to do this? Is it to reuse content on multiple pages (as a view composer might solve), or another reason?

Comment: @KirkBeard, instead of writing it this way
  public function about()
    {
        return view('about');
    }
    public function home()
    {
        return view('home');
    }

    public function contact()
    {
        return view('contact');
    }
I want to use one single function to return all of them

Comment: You could write a single method to check the current URI and show a different template to match, but it would end up being more code than just writing three [view routes](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/routing#view-routes) instead. It'll also be easier to work with, and expand upon in the future if needed.

Comment: @KirkBeard How can I do that? I would prefer to use one method to solve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use route params for it.

Define route in **web.php**:

```php
Route::get('/{page}', [IndexController::class, 'index'])->name('index');
```

Then in the controller use this:

```php
public function index(string $page) 
{
  
  if (!in_array($page, ['about', 'contact', 'home']) {
    abort(404);
  }

  return view($page);
}
```

Comment: worked like magic!

Answer (score -1):

you can use the `view()->first()` method to return the first view file that exists in the specified array of views.

for example:

```
public function index()
{
    return view()->first(['about', 'contact', 'home']);
}
```

Comment: I want the contents of the pages to be different